# Print hashes when a file or a folder is drag'n'droped to terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, drag-and-drop, lxqt

I need a way to quickly see hashes of singular files and of all files in a given folder. Drag'n'drop should work great, but in lxqt you can't drag'n'drop to scripts or even desktop entries.

I have [a script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63318233/2792852) that opens the terminal and receives one file at a time and prints its hash. I need it to be able to recognize a folder too and to hash all files in it. The problem is I don't know bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=$' \t\r\n' read -d '' -p "Drag'n'drop file to hash: " -rsn 1 str &&
    [ "$str" ];do
    while IFS= read -d '' -rsn 1 -t .02 char
    do str+="$char"
    done
    if [ "$str" ] ;then
        read -a req <<<"$str"
        echo ''
        md5sum $req
        echo ''
    fi
  done
```

Comment: Read `man -k inotify`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This recognizes a file and a folder, including files in nested folders and paths with spaces. As a bonus, shows info in the terminal name instead of printing it every time.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -ne "\033]0;Drag & drop file or folder\007"
while IFS=$'\t\r\n' read -d '' -rsn 1 str && [ "$str" ]; do
    while IFS= read -d '' -rsn 1 -t .02 char; do
        str+="$char"
    done
    if [ "$str" ]; then
        find "$str" -type f -exec md5sum {} \;
    fi
done
```